# Bubble reveal using HTML canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, canvas

I am new to using canvas, and I am wondering if it is possible to achieve a bubble reveal effect using it.

Essentially, I want to reveal the part of the image under the mouse when the user clicks inside the canvas, but hides it when the user release the mouse anywhere on the page. I think this can easily be done using a mask or an overlaying div, but I want to use a canvas for its versatility.

Here's my try... https://jsfiddle.net/vmoj2bj4/12/

```
function update() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "#666666";
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,400,400);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#ffffff"
    ctx.arc(clientX, clientY, 10, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.save(); //tried using this + restore

    if(mouseDown){
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(clientX, clientY, 100, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
      ctx.clip();
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    }
    else{
      ctx.restore(); //tried using this + save
    }

    requestAnimationFrame(update);
}
```

but I have no idea why the clip is stacking. Any help would be much appreciated!!

Comment: You call restore only when the mouse is released, but save every time. You will restore only one saved state, which leaves a lot of unrestored states on your context. Either call restore every time, either use globalCompositeOperation, which will provide better performances and less risk of a memory leak like the one you hust created.

Comment: @kaiido has your solution. Canvas with gray HTML background.  On mouse down draw an opaque circle. Set compositing to source-in and draw the whole image. The image will only appear in the circle. On mouse up just clear the canvas

Comment: Thank you guys so much!! globalCompositeOperation worked like a charm + got rid of the memory leaks. Here's the updated fiddle: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/u7q3pqyx/2)